# Crystal Reports Viewer showing thousands of pages

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-viewer

**3 page document repeating to 48,387 pages.**

I have a NextGen driven form that uses Crystal Reports to generate a document. I'm not familiar with Crystal Reports, but am trying to help troubleshoot this issue.

When we try to view this 2 page document (3 if you count the blank page), it shows as 48,387 pages. I reviewed the document in the Cystal Reports Viewer and it shows the 3 pages repeating over and over again. Does anyone have any insight into why this would occur? It seems to be looping the 3 pages over and over.

It started to happen yesterday. The only thing that may have changed on the Server, is that Hurricane Irma is about to visit us in Orlando, and we know the server team has initiated some disaster recovery plans. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely is happening because of a join.  If you have a sql like this

select ... from tableA inner join tableB on X=Y

and both tables contain 1 record the statement will return 1 record. If tableB contains 5 records , which satisfy the condition (X=Y) then the statement will return 5 records. Most likely somebody generated 50 thousands new records. It is possible also that the records were generated in different tables for example 10 records in tableA and 5 records in tableB may cause the statement above to return 50 records. You may also check the join clause, may be it is incorrect.